# C# for Winmo6.5: How to export Cab?

Tags: c#, windows, mobile, extract, cab

Okay so let's say my application is ready and I need to export cab file so I can install it on my phone. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a new "Smart Device CAB Project" (File > Add > New Project > Other Project Types > Setup and Deployment > Smart Device CAB Project) to your solution and then add your other project as an output. [How to create a windows mobile (Smart Device) .Cab installer](http://www.mobilepractices.com/2008/02/how-to-create-windows-mobile-smart.html)

Comment: have you use sqlite for windows ce ? I am having a problem with sqlinterop dll error...

Comment: No I haven't - you may want to post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use other types of deployments, such as an installer that is generated by [Mobile Packager](http://www.mobilepackager.com) We have used it to package our application files and  bundle multiple third party CABs including .NET compact framework and has an option to only installs a CAB it if it is not already installed.